# Handler wont SetText on Button

Tags: android, button, android-asynctask, android-handler

In my Application I am trying to simply `setText()` on my `Button purchaseButton`.
I have an Alert Dialog that takes a value and initializes an AsyncTask to complete the server call to find the discount.

All of that works fine, its when I get to the `onPostExecute()`.

**onPostExecute():**

```
protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
            Log.d(tag,"Result of POST: " + result);
            if(result != null){
                if(result.equals("NO")){
                    createAlert(1);

                }else{
                    result = result.replaceAll("YES", "");
                    String discount = result;
                    discountPrice = price - Double.parseDouble(discount);
                    Log.d(tag, "Discount price after pull:" + discountPrice);
                    //setPurchase("Purchase $" + String.valueOf(discountPrice));

                    new Thread(new Runnable()
                    {
                        @Override
                        public void run()
                        {
                            Message msg = handler.obtainMessage();
                            msg.what = (int) discountPrice;
                            handler.sendMessage(msg);
                        }
                    }).start();

                }
            }
```

You can see that I make a call to a handler from a new Thread(). This allows me to get to the handler but never sets the text of the button from the handler.

Handler Method:

```
final static Handler handler = new Handler(){
        @Override
        public void handleMessage(Message msg){
            Log.d(tag, "entered handler");
            if(msg.what == discountPrice)
            {
                setPurchaseText(msg.what);
            }
        }
    };
```

setPurchaseText() method:

```
private static void setPurchaseText(int value){
        Log.d(tag, "Entered setPurchaseText");
        purchaseButton.setText("Purchase $" + String.valueOf(value));
    }
```

From my knowledge this should allow me to set the text from the handler. Why is it not setting the text and how can I get it to set the text with my string value?

Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: What for do you need this Handler anyways? `onPostExecute()` already runs in the UI Thread.

Comment: I have tried setText from onPost, that was my initial commands. It too will not setText.@SimonSays

Comment: you dont need to use String.valueOf(value) just do this "Purchase $"+value); this will concatenate the integer value

Comment: If the `setText()` wasn't working in `onPostExecute()` then the problem is elsewhere. Did you debug to see that you are getting the correct `result` from `doInBackground()`? Are you getting an error or is the text just not changing?

Comment: I did end up getting it to work form your comment earlier, it made me look deeper and found it in a Double.parseDouble(String). Thanks, it now works onPostExecute

Answer (score 1):

If the `setText()` is not working in `onPostExecute()`, they you might not be creating your `AsyncTask` on the UI thread. `AsyncTask` runs `onPostExecute()` on the thread you create it.

Again, `Handler` is created on the currently executed `Thread`. May be your `Handler` is initialized on a background thread. Try using `final static Handler handler = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper())`. This ensures the handler to be attached to the main thread.